# How to check if instruction is a PHI instruction in LLVM IR

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I am writing an LLVM pass. For an instruction (llvm::Instruction Class), how can I check if an instruction is a PHI instruction?

Comment: Would a `dyn_cast<PHINode>(x) == NULL` have worked?

Comment: Mystical - yup, something similar, that is, isa<PHINode>(x), worked for me!

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution. You can check for a PHI node like this, `isa<PHINode>(inst)`.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that `isa` existed. To that's a +1 from me.

Comment: @Mystical, http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html is a good source of information :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Instruction* I;

    if(I->getOpcode()==Instruction::PHI){
    //code
    }
```

Comment: the isa<> solution is how these checks should be carried out. If I had enough reputation I would downvoat this so you should maybe delete it.

Comment: @baibo Do you mean that for a higher level instruction like `PHINode`, `isa` is more idiomatic? Is there any room for error or any maintainability issue with using the opcode?

Comment: @Hari No idea, I wrote this 8 years ago and I have since long moved away from working on LLVM. Maybe it is :D