# How to identify any type of instruction in LLVM/C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, llvm-clang

I've been asked to do a LLVM function that allows me to find: jump/branch, load/store, call, 'arithmetic and other type of instruction'.

As far as I managed to do, I've been able to find the CallInst, LoadInst, StoreInst and BranchInst doing the following code with dyn_cast:

```
for (const Function &F : *M) 
    for (const BasicBlock &BB : F) 
        for (const Instruction &I : BB) 
            if (const StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) 
                 count++;;
```

I'm struggling to find a way of extracting all the arithmetic and 'other type' instructions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can get airthmetic instructions by dyn_casting it to llvm::BinaryOperator. And then get the opcode of the binary instruction by calling BinOp->getOpcode(). Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 10):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470505/how-to-check-if-instruction-is-a-phi-instruction-in-llvm-ir)

Use

```
if (llvm::isa <llvm::LoadInst> (I))
```

or `llvm::StoreInst`, etc.

For instruction containing binary operators, `llvm::isa <llvm::BinaryOperator> (I)` can't differentiate them. Use

```
if (!strncmp(I.getOpcodeName(), "add", 4))
```

or

```
if (I.getOpcode == llvm::Add)
```

You can find the OpcodeNames and Opcode [here](http://llvm.org/doxygen/Instruction_8cpp_source.html) and [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def)

Comment: `I.getOpcode` would be `I.getOpcode()`